# Is there an operator that generates a set of combinations from a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, computer-science

Example Input: $$\mathbb{S} = \{1,2,3\}$$

Proposed Operator: $$\mathbb{C} = \operatorname{K}(\mathbb{S},k=2)$$

Example Output:  $$\mathbb{C} = \Big\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\Big\}$$

Side note: the operator $C^{n}_{k}$ for finding the number of $k$-size combinations in $\mathbb{S}$ itself is surprisingly common.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard name for that operator, not even a standard name for it in computer languages that implement it. If you need it in something you're writing, just define and use it locally. I wouldn't call the result $\mathbb{C}$, which usually stands for the complex numbers.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thank you for clarifying. It does seems surprising though -- seems like such a fundamental everyday operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "operator" is simply called the *set of $k$-subsets of $S$*.
From the literature, I know of at least four different notations for it:
$$
\mathcal{P}_k(S), \space [S]^k, \space \binom{S}{k} \space \text{and} \space  S^{(k)}.
$$
Choose your favorite one!

Answer (score 1):

Something I've commonly seen written is
$$\binom{\mathbb S}2$$
This obviously generalizes to $n$-element sets. When the top element in the binomial symbol is a set, there's really only one thing you can mean.

Comment: Some people might object to this because in zfc "everything is a set" but I like it and have seen it a lot also.

Comment: @Daniel They'd be right, but I'm sure you agree that it's unnecessarily pedantic. Could say instead that it's not a number.